# Ошибка при чтении файла в WinApi.

Tags: winapi, handle

подскажите в чем ошибка в моем коде? Функция ReadFile возвращает false. Если закомментировать строку "num = num * 10 + ((const char)lengthStrFile[i] - '0');" то чтение происходит нормально. в чем проблема?

```
HANDLE FileHandle = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)TEXT("file.txt"),
    GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

char * lengthStrFile;
DWORD bytesRead;
bool isOk ;
int num = 0;
int j;
isOk = ReadFile(FileHandle, lengthStrFile, sizeof(char) * 8, &bytesRead, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if (lengthStrFile[i] == '$'){
        for (j = 0; j < i;j++){
            num = num * 10 + ((const char)lengthStrFile[i] - '0');
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Первая ошибка: не проверяется результат CreateFile. Вторая ошибка - чтение в неинициализированный указатель lengthStrFile, который еще и указывает на невыделенный буфер (то есть неизвестно куда). Подозреваю, что третья ошибка в том, что вы не читаете сообщения компилятора.

Comment: Почитайте про GetLastError,и отпишите